# Beamer dynamics with tcolorbox

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, transparency

How can I make a box of the tcolorbox-package appear in a beamer presentation? For exemple I want the box to appear together with point 3...

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames},graphics]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{A slide}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item<1-> Point 1
 \item<2-> Point 2
 \item<3-> Point 3
 \begin{tcolorbox}
  A box with text               
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item<4-> Point 4
 \end{itemize}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Either you've missed an `\end{itemize}`... or the first `\begin{itemize}` was unintended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a spurious `\begin{itemize}`. Removing that allows the code to compile and the box appears with the third point, as desired.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames},graphics]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{A slide}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item<1-> Point 1
 \item<2-> Point 2
 \item<3-> Point 3
 \begin{tcolorbox}
  A box with text
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \item<4-> Point 4
 \end{itemize}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: box in point 3]